# Get Attribute Value in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

How do I get the value of a specific attribute? I use the code:

```
$attributes = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($product['product_id']);                 
if (!empty($attributes)) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attr) {  
        if($attr['attribute_id'] == 15) {              
            $attr_text = $attr['text'] ;
            $attr = $this->dd->createElement('param');
            $attr->setAttribute('code', 'color');
            $attr->setAttribute('name', 'Color');
            $attr->appendChild($this->dd->createTextNode($attr_text));
            $e->appendChild($attr);
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work. How to get the value of a variable in OpenCart 2.3

```
$attr['text']
```

Comment: Best way to not get an answer: "it does not work". Why does it not work? What does it say? Tell us everything you can, provided you have an [MCVE]

Comment: did you try `var_dump` of `$attr`?

Answer (score 0):

First off all, new get grouped attributes from getProductAttributes(), you need to create new function in model for attribute information by ID.

```
public function getProductAttributeById($product_id, $attribute_id) {
    $product_attribute_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND attribute_id = '" . (int)$attribute_id . "'");

    return $query->row;
}
```

**Code not tested!!!**

And then you use it like this:

```
$attributes_by_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributeById($product['product_id'], 15);                 
if (!empty($attributes_by_id )) {           
     $attr_text = $attributes_by_id ['text'] ;
     $attr = $this->dd->createElement('param');
     $attr->setAttribute('code', 'color');
     $attr->setAttribute('name', 'Color');
     $attr->appendChild($this->dd->createTextNode($attr_text));
     $e->appendChild($attr);
} else {
   // default code
}
```